# startMonitoringFromRegion - what to do in didEnterRegion?

Tags: ios, ios4, core-location

I'm currently implementing startMonitoringFromRegion:

```
-  (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{   
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;


    if (![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable] ||
        ![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled])
        return;

    CLLocationDegrees radius = 5;
    if (radius > self.locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance)
        radius = self.locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;


    CLRegion* region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:self.currentLocation.coordinate
                                                               radius:radius 
                                                           identifier:@"Indentifier"];

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];
    [region release];

}
```

When I enter a new region didEnterRegion will get called.
My question here is, what should I do in didEnterRegion?

I have an array of all my coordinates. Should I extract region.center and compare that coordinate to my array of coordinates, and see which one of the coordinates that's closest to region.center?

Comment: Your code looks wrong? 
You create a new region based on your current location. Every time didUpdateToLocation is called, you overwrite that region with your new location. That means, you will never exit the region you create because the region moves with you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noted that CLRegion has a wonderful method called containsCoordinate.

So instead of looping through all my McDonald's array coordinates in didEnterRegion and check if their distance is less than x kilometers from region.center, I can now just use containsCoordinate.

```
for (Restaurant *restaurant in arrRestaurants)
{
    CLLocation *restaurantLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[resturant.latitude doubleValue] longitude:[restraurant.longitude doubleValue]];

    if ([region containsCoordinate: restaurantLocation.coordinate])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"McDonads found in the region!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", restaurant.town] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];         
    }
}
```

Now, I haven't tried this yet, but to me it seems logical.

Comment: will this approach retrieve an accurate location when it triggers the didEnterRegion?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the `-didEnterRegion` and `-didExitRegion` methods for your CLLocationManager. You would execute your code based on what you need to happen for entering/exiting the region.

I have edited my answer based on your comment. If you need to calculate the distance between you and your point, you can do it this way.

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

You could create your location point from region.center.

Comment: My array of coordinates represents McDonalds restaurants. So when you enter a region I want to alert the user that he just entered a region where there is x number of McDonalds restaurants. Should I compare region.center (which I get from didEnterRegion) with my array of coordinates that represents McDonalds restaurants, and then calculate the distance to see if there is any restaurants in that region?

Comment: Do you know how large your region is? I know there is a size limitation on how big a region you can create. If it isn't too excessive, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: My question is the logic around the didEnterRegion. Is my last comment correct in the sense how you should use didEnterRegion for my purpose? To compare the distance between region.center and the coordinates in my McDonald's array? Whould you do like that?